# React Native Error: The component for route must be a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, routes, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a basic setup for react navigation, but for some reason, when I go to view the project, I get a blank screen and an error in terminal that says:

```
Error: The component for route 'screens' must be a React component. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
screens: MyScreen,
}

You can also use a navigator:

import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator';
...
screens: MyNavigator,
}
```

I've looked at other Stack Overflow solutions, but none of them seem to apply in my case, so, is there something else I'm doing wrong here?

My **App.js** (Also importing fonts here, but these worked, it seems to be an issue with the routing)

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import Navigator from './routes/homeStack';

const getFonts = () => Font.loadAsync({
    'raleway-regular': require('./assets/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf'),
    'raleway-bold': require('./assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf')
  });
export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  
  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return (
      <Navigator />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync= {getFonts}
        onFinish= {()=> setFontsLoaded(true)}
        onError= {()=> console.log('error')} 
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**homeStack.js**

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from '../screens/home';
import Scanner from '../screens/scanner';

const screens = {
    Home: {
        screen: Home
    },
    Scanner: {
        screen: Scanner
    },
};

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({screens});
export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

**home.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, } from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <Text style={globalStyles.titleText}>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**scanner.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';

export default function Scanner() {
  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <Text>About Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**My file directory**

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is that package you are using? react-navigation? Isn't everyone using [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) by now?

Comment: @MaximilianDietel Yeah, it is react navigation, specifically following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMX6GP1TXGo

Comment: If you're using latest version of react-navigation, you can use guide described here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello react-navigation.

Comment: @НиколайГольцев hm, I think if this still doesn't work, I will just completely retry with the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video you are following along with is really old and probably not up to date anymore. Please follow the [installation guides](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) and then follow along [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) guide. That should get you up and running in minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I followed the tutorial and everything is working now

Comment: Thats great! Consider upvoting or marking my answer as correct in that case! That would be the the best way to thank me